# What is the correct and conventional way to express the Dirichlet eta function as Dirichlet characters in Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

What is the correct and conventional way to express the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) as Dirichlet characters in Mathematica?

```
Table[(2*DirichletCharacter[2, 1, n] - 1)/n^s, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

or only the numerators as a finite sequence:

```
Table[(2*DirichletCharacter[2, 1, n] - 1), {n, 1, 12}]
```

{1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1}

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Modulus_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it is easy to check in Mathematica that the infinite sum using DirichletCharacter[]

```
Sum[(2 DirichletCharacter[2, 1, n] - 1)/n^s, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[38]= 2^-s (-2 + 2^s) Zeta[s] *)
```

is indeed DirichletEta[s]

```
% == DirichletEta[s] // FullSimplify

(* Out[37]= True *)
```

Comment: Yes I see.I have another question about this though: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895070/what-is-the-symmetric-functional-equation-of-the-dirichlet-eta-function

Comment: But thanks for the effort. Not directly related either but I am seeking to apply the symmetric functional equation here: http://www.lmfdb.org/L/degree1/

Comment: Another way to express the first relation: `2 DirichletL[2, 1, s] - DirichletL[1, 1, s] == DirichletEta[s] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: As to your first comment: why not check the validity of the two formulas in Mathematica, at least numerically?